# Javascript + ExpressJS - return [something] or return (nothing)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, return

What is the difference between to return something and to return nothing?

For an example:

```
user.save(function(err){
  if ( err && err.code !== 11000 ) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.code);
    res.send('Another error showed up');
    return;
  }

  //duplicate key
  if ( err && err.code === 11000 ) {
    req.flash('error', 'User already exists');
    res.redirect('/signup');
    return;
  }

  res.locals.user = user;
  req.session.user = user;
  //res.locals.session = req.session;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

It seems that it has no difference them at all if I `return res;` or just `return` (nothing):

```
  //duplicate key
  if ( err && err.code === 11000 ) {
    req.flash('error', 'User already exists');
    res.redirect('/signup');
    return res;
  }
```

It is quite hard for me to understand **without** `returning` anything.

So why and what are the reasons we only use `return` itself?

And for the case like mine above, why don't we `return res;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `user.save(function callback(){})` that function inside of save() is a callback function, it will invoke after you user data saved to database.

Secondly, `user.save()` did not expecting any return value, this callback function will just been invoked after save.

so `return` in this callback function is to break/stop the function go toward running, its mean finished.

Since `user.save()` didn't expect any return value, so you can return nothing or anything, this `return` will just tell the function is end, no matter what you return, it will not being used anyway.

Hope this clear your confusion.:)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to return anything here. Making res.redirect('/') would just redirect you to the appropriate callback

This function is a callback and has no requirement to return anything.
Anything you return wont have any impact on the functionality